# Chips are not working in the Materialize css version alph 1.0

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I have used materialize.css before. Recently I tried using the new version Alpha 1.0 but the [Chips](http://next.materializecss.com/chips.html) aren't getting added.

I used the code from the docs

```
<div class="chips"></div>
```

and include this in my js file

```
 $('.chips').chips();
```

But I keep getting the following error on my console

> materialize.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'addEventListener' of undefined

What should I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

This issue was fixed in `1.0.0-alpha.2`.

Check the changelog at https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/releases/tag/1.0.0-alpha.2:

> 1.0.0-alpha.2 (November 30th)
>
> ---
>
> - Chips
>
>   - Fixed and standardized chips callback parameters

Use that version and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @yuriy636, can you please answer [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898366/getting-chips-data-in-materialize-css-through-post)