# Getting chips data in Materialize css through Post

Tags: materialize, materialized

I am trying to get the data using the Materilize css's chips. But no data is received when I try to submit it using a form.
I checked that the input fields value was null once I added the chips.

I wrote a jquery code to verify this

```
$('#showvalues').on('click', function(){
    alert($('#emotiontags').val())   
})
```

and my chips code looks like

```
<div class="chips chips-autocomplete col s4 offset-s3">
    <input placeholder="You Emotions" id="emotiontags" type="text" 
    name="emotiontags">
</div>

<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="showvalues">
   Show values
   <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
</button>
```

Here is its out with normal text [image]

and here is the output when I try to add chips[image]

Answer (score 4):

Well it has been 6 months but I wanted to give an answer for people encountering this question. According to the documentation of MaterializeCSS, `chipsData` is the property that stores an array of the current chips data.

After getting the instance of your chips elements by something like this;

```
var chipInstance = M.Chips.getInstance($(".chips"));
```

Chips array can be accessed and logged to the console via

```
console.log(chipInstance.chipsData);
```

Comment: Could you please add an example or piece of code to show the usage of 'chipsData' property?

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra added the example.